# Why simple count down timer android application giving ANR issue?

Tags: android, operating-system, android-anr-dialog

We have one application which is having the MapFragment and count down timer. We used this app for 1 hr with the Acer tablet (Android 6) with 1 GB RAM and it works perfect. Now, we used new latest Acer tablet with 2 GB RAM (Android 7) for 4 hrs.

After using 4 hrs of test we are getting ANR issue. Also, lot of apps on the system are giving same ANR issue like Settings app, Clock App, Chrome App. This device has remained with ample amount of storage. But, memory it is showing 1.8 gb used (92 %).

I tried to reproduce the same issue on another new tablet ( Acer tablet with 2 GB RAM (Android 7)) but i couldn't able to reproduce it. (I tried lot of cases by running the app up to 1 hr but i haven't run app for 4 hr.)

Is it a RAM issue or It is because of some system problem?
Or is it because of some system updates and incompatibility of the app?
Or it is due to my android app?

Can anyone please suggest the best way to tackle such unusual scenario

Comment: Are you using some kinf of counters like counter++;  If so it can reach for example Integer limits and crash

Comment: @VygintasB Thanks for response. I checked that but the end time is around 1 year and i handled that case. But in this case it is not going in exception case. Also lot of apps on the tablet is giving the ANR issue in 30 sec.

Comment: You're probably creating a new object or doing something expensive each time with the timer and forget to release the memory.